# Changing icon of button on tinymce menu bar

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-3

I have a custom menu bar plugin for `TinyMCE-3.5.10`. One of the buttons, marked play is created thus:

```
 case 'play':
    playBtn = cm.createButton('play', {
    title : 'Play',
    image : 'tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/mainMenuBar/img/play.png',
    onclick : function() {
     readText();
    }
 });
   return playBtn;
```

My question:
1. How can I change the image icon for this button programmatically? The command `playBtn.renderHTML()` does provide me the `HTML` code with the `src` parameter showing the location of the image. If I parse the HTML string and change the `src` parameter to point to a new image, how do I associate this string with the button again?

Comment: if you can get the playBtn, then you can use jquery to set the source of the image like this:  $(playBtn).attr("src", "myImage.png"); or with classic javascript like this document.getElementById("imageid").src="yourImage.png";

Comment: @RubenVerschueren: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried the jQuery solution you suggested. That did not work.